# Message pact - Scala async/event-driven example?

Tags: scala, pact

I am new to Pact, CDC testing and Scala. I am trying to learn how to do CDC testing for event-driven Scala. I have found the examples for scala-pact and have found these useful for learning how to implement contracts for RESTful Scala services.

Now I am looking for an example of CDC tests for event-driven Scala. Can anyone kindly point me to one if one exists? I found this example in Kotlin, looking for something similar in Scala:

https://github.com/rafaroca/pact-msg.

Comment: Take a look to https://github.com/BBVA/contract-testing. Thera are examples in Scala.

Comment: There's a nice library : https://github.com/ITV/scala-pact